# Blender3.3 win10 snapping to surface not working

Tags: blender

I will try to put it simply, I am following the donut tutorial from youtube.

[my working window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrmH9.png)

[my snap setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z18ao.png)

[porprotional editing setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g99RE.png)

[This is when I try to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE1kl.png)

[The result (it dont work)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm1gh.png)

Your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to deselect the magnet [image] button, it's easier to use `Ctrl` when snapping objects, this also might be the case your snapping isn't working.

Grab vertex with `g` key, hold `ctrl` and drag it around your donut

[image: Magnet]